# PHP Crawler to use plain text on description

Tags: php, search, web-crawler

What to change from my crawler to use page content as description if there is no meta description available or if it is under 10 characters? I want it to take a maximum of 30 characters for description.

Here is the code:

```
    <?php
if(!isset($crawlToken) || $crawlToken!=418941){
 if(!isset($_GET['78wc58v'])){
  die("Error");
 }
}
ini_set("display_errors", "on");
$dir=realpath(dirname(__FILE__));
include($dir."/../inc/config.php");
function shutdown(){ 
 global $dir;
 $error = error_get_last();
 if($error !== NULL && $error['type'] === E_ERROR) {
  file_put_contents($dir."/crawlStatus.txt", "0");
  get_headers(HOST."/crawler/runCrawl.php");
 }
}
set_time_limit(0);
register_shutdown_function('shutdown');

include($dir."/PHPCrawl/libs/PHPCrawler.class.php");
include($dir."/simple_html_dom.php");

function addURL($t, $u, $d){
 global $dbh;
 if($t!="" && filter_var($u, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)){
  $check=$dbh->prepare("SELECT `id` FROM `search` WHERE `url`=?");
  $check->execute(array($u));
  $t=preg_replace("/\s+/", " ", $t);
  $t=substr($t, 0, 1)==" " ? substr_replace($t, "", 0, 1):$t;
  $t=substr($t, -1)==" " ? substr_replace($t, "", -1, 1):$t;
  $t=html_entity_decode($t, ENT_QUOTES);
  $d=html_entity_decode($d, ENT_QUOTES);
  echo $u."<br/>\n";
  ob_flush();
  flush();
  if($check->rowCount()==0){
   $sql=$dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO `search` (`title`, `url`, `description`) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
   $sql->execute(array(
    $t,
    $u,
    $d
   ));
  }else{
   $sql=$dbh->prepare("UPDATE `search` SET `description` = ?, `title` = ? WHERE `url`=?");
   $sql->execute(array(
    $d,
    $t,
    $u
   ));
  }
 }
}
class WSCrawler extends PHPCrawler { 
 function handleDocumentInfo(PHPCrawlerDocumentInfo $p){ 
  $u=$p->url;
  $c=$p->http_status_code;
  $s=$p->source;
  if($c==200 && $s!=""){
   $html = str_get_html($s);
   if(is_object($html)){
    $d="";
    $do=$html->find("meta[name=description]", 0);
    if($do){
     $d=$do->content;
    }
    $t=$html->find("title", 0);
    if($t){
     $t=$t->innertext;
     addURL($t, $u, $d);
    }
    $html->clear(); 
    unset($html);
   }
  }
 }
}
function crawl($u){
 $C = new WSCrawler();
 $C->setURL($u);
 $C->addContentTypeReceiveRule("#text/html#");
 $C->addURLFilterRule("#(jpg|gif|png|pdf|jpeg|svg|css|js)$# i");
 if(!isset($GLOBALS['bgFull'])){
  $C->setTrafficLimit(2000 * 1024);
 }
 $C->obeyRobotsTxt(true);
 $C->obeyNoFollowTags(true);
 $C->setUserAgentString("Nevo (../about/bot.php)");
 $C->setFollowMode(0);
 $C->go();
}
if(!isset($url4Array)){
 // Get the last indexed URLs (If there isn't, use default URL's) & start Crawling
 $last=$dbh->query("SELECT `url` FROM search");
 $count=$last->rowCount();
 if($count < 1){
  crawl("http://localhost"); // The Default URL #1
 }else{
  $urls=$last->fetchAll();
  $index=rand(0, $count-1);
  crawl($urls[$index]['url']);
 }
}elseif(is_array($url4Array)){
 foreach($url4Array as $url){
  crawl($url);
 }
}
?>
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you are stuck on here. Don't you just need to modify `handleDocumentInfo()` with the logic you have specified?

Comment: Can you help me with that, not that much php experience, how do I make it get page content (text)?

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing here, since I haven't heard of `PHPCrawler` and don't have it to hand for testing. This would replace the fetching of the description in `handleDocumentInfo`.

```
$do = $html->find("meta[name=description]", 0);
$description = $do ? $do->content : '';

if (!$description) {
    // You'll need to work out how to get a text copy of
    // page content - maybe this?
    $do = $html->find("body", 0);
    $description = $do->content;
}
```

Naturally, I advise you not to expect this to work verbatim. Play around with it, and you'll get something working.

I've switched some variables too: `$d` isn't at all descriptive as to what it does.

Answer (score 1):

```
$do=$html->find("meta[name=description]", 0);
if($do){
 $d=$do->content;
} else {
 $do = $html->find("p",0); // OR $html->find("h2",0) OR whatever;
 $d = substr($do->plaintext,0,30); // just 30  chars
}
```

If no meta description, get first "p" or "h2"

Comment: You can do directly load all html in $do, and then $do->plaintext;